# comparing and contrasting Sybase and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sybase

They share common history, they run on different operating systems. This is the part I know.

- what parts remain the same?
- which have changed since they split?
- is SQL Server knowledge still applicable to Sybase?
- what features available in Sql Server are not present in Sybase?
- which features that are present in Sybase are not available in SQL Server?

I'm interested in answers from people with comparable experience in both platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common history until <strike>15 years ago</strike> 1994 up until SQL Server 4.21. SQL Server 6.0, 6.5 were splits. SQL Server 7 was a complete re-write and it was a truly different product to SQL Server 6.0, 6.5 which were the last of the "shared" code base.

The features are quite similar and a lot of system tables and stored procs can be run on both. However, the 2 systems don't really have much in common now except the locking strategy (as compared to Oracle or MVCC based systems).

Saying that, basic SQL is portable between the 2 and I've ported Sybase to SQL Server before.

I've also worked in/or with teams that manage both platform teams but the overlap is not as much as you expect or perhaps hope for.

Why do you ask? I wouldn't plan a career on Sybase unless you work in Banking IT...

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to the ANSI SQL syntax, they are the very much the same; but they do vary, and sometimes maddeningly so.

Since each vendor wants to get you to migrate onto their platform, I would search for the how-to-migrate-x-to-y documents on their websites.  They will give you a good idea of the documented differences.

Answer (score 0):

The latest published SQL Server benchmarks are at about 1.2 mil tran/min. That is roughtly 16k transactions per second, at system priced at USD ~6 mil in 2005 (64 way Superdome).

Sybase ASE 16.0 was tested with success at 200 0000 tran/sec
Sybase ASE has a strog SAP Replication Server superior(it Primary faild the transacton are saved in stable queue) net to  MS SQL server wich has a simple replication(if Primary faild it will louse transcations)